# Validation for a user form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, form

I have a really bad habit at the moment with writing global specific functions to handle data and feel like I could reduce my work load by stop copying the same.

Basically I have a registration form that performs in line validation and didn't want to use an external library like jQuery Validate. My validation performs as the user has focused out the box and flags an error if there is one.

So here's some HTML form data:

```
 <div class="inputs">    
  <input class="required" type="text" name="first_name" id="register_first_name" />
  <input class="required" type="text" name="last_name" id="register_last_name" />
  <input class="required" type="text" name="email" id="register_email" />
  <input class="required" type="text" name="telephone" id="register_telephone" />
 </div>
```

Javascript that clears errors:

```
/** Remove red error_show borders **/
jQuery(document).on('blur keypress change autocompletechange', '#register_first_name', function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("error_show");
});

jQuery(document).on('blur keypress change autocompletechange', '#register_last_name', function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("error_show");
});

jQuery(document).on('blur keypress change autocompletechange', '#register_email', function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("error_show");
});

jQuery(document).on('blur keypress change autocompletechange', '#register_telephone', function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("error_show");
});
```

Javascript that runs functions when data has been entered:

```
jQuery(document).on( 'blur change autocompletechange', '#register_first_name', function() {
    formatHyphenatedLastname('#register_first_name');
    validFirstname(jQuery("#register_first_name").val());} );

jQuery(document).on( 'blur change autocompletechange', '#register_last_name', function() {
    formatHyphenatedLastname('#register_last_name');
    validLastname(jQuery("#register_last_name").val())

    } );    

jQuery(document).on( 'blur autocompletechange change', '#register_telephone', function() {  
    uppercaseField('#register_telephone'); 
    collapseSpaces('#register_telephone')
    validTelephone(jQuery("#register_telephone").val());
});

jQuery(document).on( 'blur', '#register_email', function() {  lowercaseField('#register_email');
                                                                checkEmail(jQuery("#register_email").val());
                                                            });
```

Register.js:

```
function validFirstname(firstname)
{

jQuery(".firstname.input").find(".required").removeClass("valid");
 if(!firstname || firstname.length === 0 )
 }
 else{
    jQuery(".firstname.input").find(".required").addClass("valid");
 }
}

function validLastname(lastname)
{
 jQuery(".lastname.input").find(".required").removeClass("valid");
 if(!lastname || lastname.length === 0 )
 {
 }
 else{
    jQuery(".lastname.input").find(".required").addClass("valid");
 }
}

function formatHyphenatedLastname(field)
{
f=trim(jQuery(field).val());
// first sentance case it
f=sentenceCase(f);
// no sort double barrelled names
if(f.indexOf("-"))
    {
    p=f.indexOf("-");
    f=f.substring(0,p+1)+f.substring(p+1,p+2).toUpperCase()+f.substring(p+2);
    }
// sort mcs and macs
if(f.indexOf("Mc")==0 || (f.indexOf("Mc")==f.indexOf("-Mc")+1) )
    {
    p=f.indexOf("Mc");
    f=f.substring(0,p+2)+f.substring(p+2,p+3).toUpperCase()+f.substring(p+3);
    }
jQuery(field).val(f);
}

function validTelephone(phone)
{
    pattern = /^((\(?0\d{4}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|(\(?0\d{3}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|(\(?0\d{2}\)?\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?$/i;
    jQuery(".telephone.input").children(".sidetip").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(".telephone.input").find(".required").removeClass("valid");
    if(!pattern.test(phone))
    {
        jQuery(".telephone.input").children(".sidetip").children(".invalid").addClass("active");
    }
    else{
        //jQuery(".telephone.input").children(".sidetip").children(".ok").addClass("active");
        jQuery(".telephone.input").find(".required").addClass("valid");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm sort of writing the same function over and over again but checking against different parameters and it's just making the code look really messy and difficult to debug.

I've looked into a module pattern but I just don't know how this can implemented on such individual and specific inputs.

Answer (score 2):

By quickly glancing at the code, I think `Register.js` file is kinda allright. You have lot of code duplication in the first two examples that can be solved with general wrapping function.

You want the shared functionality for the inputs you need to be targeted by class rather than by id's.

You could create general function for removing errors:

```
function removeError() {
    this.removeClass('error_show');
}
```

and then just pass this function as callback to all the inputs:

```
$('input.required').each(function(el, index) {
    el.on('blur keypress change autocompletechange', removeError);
});
```

Comment: With the .each function, can that be ran on document.ready?